# Investment strategy in index funds during the start of the bear market

Tags: united-kingdom, index-fund

It's kind of a newbie question but I was preparing to invest in index funds (low-cost index funds) for a while now and I am just thinking what should my strategy look like.

As of the day of writing this post, there was a big drop (around 5%) in S&P 500 and other index funds, what should my strategy look like.

I am not sure if the bear market starts, or this is just a fluctuation.

The question is, how should I invest in index funds under the circumstances?

Shall I just invest a certain amount for the next years and don't care about the bear or bull market at all?

Or maybe I should invest part of the money in index funds and the rest in other commodities?

Shall I invest different amounts depending on the direction of the market?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I have been thinking about index funds too. I think it's a good diversification technique. However, **I am new to investing** like with any advice run it through your own investing philosophy and common sense.

I am going to look into ETFs and Index funds soon.

**The current trend**

What I have read, and you should research for yourself, is that this is a likely a fluctuation. These have been rare recently because of a very strong market.

It's the first 'big' one I've seen so far investing and it's scary for me too but most seem to think it will pass shortly. They say that it's global market wide knock on from worries in the US about inflation due to good job and economy news. What I am thinking is have the companies I've invested in changed? Probably not. I just hope they were not overpriced when I got them. So I will be sitting tight and hoping for the best as the storm will pass.